# ranger file explorer: how to change into 2 panes at most (for vertically narrow console)

Tags: configuration, ranger

I’ve scanned the `?` commands inside `ranger` as well as some cheat sheets people made online, but to no avail.

How do I change `ranger` to **only use 2 panes (or less)**?  I don’t mind getting rid of the entirety of the file preview window, if that’s what it takes (so, turn it into `deer` in the `ranger plugin` version for `Emacs`). Or, sacrifice one panel of parent dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this with

```
set column_ratios 3,4
```

in your `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` file.

You can read `3,4` as make one pane 3 units wide and one pane 4 units wide. The left pane will show your files with the preview on the right.

It's actually in the man page inside ranger but you have to search for *column* not pane.

Comment: got it! thank you for the pointer. This is great news  =)  best regards